Google mail does not accept or send emails from/to my SMTP server
I installed Mailcow on my server and configured it. There are no problems with other emails. https://www.mail-tester.com gives 10/10.
The problem is with Google mail. If I send email to Google mail, I get this message:

host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.150.26] said:
550-5.7.1 [185.97.200.51] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to
550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your
550-5.7.1 service provider instead. For more information, go to
550 5.7.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NotAuthorizedError 38308e7fff4ca-30041b158f7si25122551fa.276 - gsmtp
(in reply to end of DATA command)

When I send email from Google mail to mine, I get this message:

The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. For more information, go to https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7720 [example.ru. IP: timed out] [mail.example.ru. IP: timed out]

There is a PTR record for the IP address, DNS is configured, DKIM and DMARK are there. Ports 25 and 587 are open and forwarded in the router.
For postfics is configured to prefer ip4 smtp_address_preference = ipv4
I read on the Internet that this can happen if your IP is in https://www.spamhaus.org, but I deleted my IP from there.
Please, tell me how to make friends with Google mail.

Related/dupe: The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to send email directly to our servers. Does your server have an SPF record in its DNS?

@RemyLebeau Yes, my server has an SPF record like: v=spf1 a mx ip4:■■■.■■.■■■.■■■ ~all
I tried to send a letter using telnet as in the question you gave me and received this answer: 550-5.7.1 [185.97.200.51] Messages missing a valid Message-ID header are not
